# Terminology for Query to group and find difference of number greater than 3?

Tags: sql

Hello everyone I am an SQL noob and can't figure this out and not sure what I need to look for terminology wise to figure it out so even just the proper terms to research would be of great help.

That said, here is the table I need to query:
[Port Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngFXg.png)

With that table I need to be able to find out which countries have more than two ports and which of those ports have a difference of more than 3 docks.

The data should be formatted to look like this:
[Final Query Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiGmJ.png)

Comment: First lessons: Try simple SELECT's. Try WHERE clause and ORDER BY.

Comment: Try giving ASCII format table or create table and insert statements in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, which countries have more than two ports, you can use like

```
SELECT COUNTRY FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY COUNTRY HAVING COUNT(PORTNAME) > 2
```

now with this result, you have to find "which of those ports have a difference of more than 3 docks."
so, you can write like

```
SELECT A.PORTNAME AS FIRSTPORT, A.NUMDOCKS AS FIRSTNUM, 
   B.PORTNAME AS SECONDPORT, B.NUMDOCKS AS SECONDOCKS,
   A.COUNTRY
FROM TABLENAME AS A, 
     TABLENAME AS B,
    (SELECT COUNTRY FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY COUNTRY HAVING COUNT(PORTNAME) > 2) AS C
WHERE A.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY
AND   B.COUNTRY = C.COUNTRY
AND   3 < (A.NUMDOCKS - B.NUMDOCKS)
```